# Calling a function from a link on Kendo Grid column

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am using AngularJS and Kendo Grid together. I have three files: HTML (containing the view to be displayed), Controller(coordinate between view and model), Service(business logic). I have a Kendo Grid and a button on view. I want the button to show/hide on the click of a link on the column of Kendo Grid. Below is the code snippet.

HTML

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div id="grid" kendo-grid k-options="kendoGrid"></div>

        <input type="button" id="myButton" ng-show="showButton"/>

    </div>

</div>
```

Service:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.service('myService', function () {
    this.showMe = false;
    this.changeShow = function(){
        this.showMe = !this.showMe;
    };
      this.getKGrid = function () {                
                var kGrid = {
                    dataSource: [{"Col1":"Val1","Col2":"Val2"}],
                    columns: [{
                        field: "Col1",
                        title: "Col1"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Col2",
                        title: "Col2",
                        template: "<a href='\\#' class='link' ng-click='this.changeShow()'>#=Col2#</a>"
                    }                                
                ]
            };
            return kGrid;
        };
});
```

Controller:

```js
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.kendoGrid = myService.getKGrid();
    $scope.showButton = myService.showMe;    
    $scope.$watch(function(){return myService.showMe;}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue == oldValue) return;
        $scope.showButton = newValue;
    }, true); 
});
```

I am able to see the Kendo Grid and the link on its column but I am not able to show/hide button on the click of this column via controller. Please help me what I need to correct here or should I follow some other approach to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.changeShow()` in your template is just a string, it is in no way connected to the actual `changeShow` function that you define in the service.

When you click on the link `ng-click` will evaluate the expression `this.changeShow()` against the current `$scope`.

You can put this in your controller to verify it:

```
$scope.changeShow = function () {
  console.log('changeShow');
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/cT6jsxbSRO9RRR6m1xgy?p=preview

There are multiple routes you could take to solve this. The easiest being moving the logic from the service into the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. After moving the function in Controller, it worked for me. Actually I did not want any logic to be present in Controller that is why was trying to figure out a way to do this via service. I am facing another problem with link click. I want to show a pop up window on the click of a column of a row which contains the detail data of that row. Something like given in http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command. But I want this to work on click of a link of an existing column rather than a new custom button from a angular service. Please guide me.

Comment: I will try to help. But please accept the answer so it will be registered as solved and ask a new questions so others may give their solutions to the new problem.